# jQuery sending parameter to Rails app to save in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to save params which is sent via jQuery tag placed in different site as a record in mysql with Rails. My jQuery tag I wrote so far is as follows.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
 var webURL = {fullUrl: window.location.href
  };//for getting complete url,or window.location.origin for domain alone.
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:3000/viewcounter/count', // count_action in viewcounter_controller
   type: "GET",
   data: webURL
    })
  });
  </script>
```

For rails part, controller called viewcounter is like this.

```
def count
url = params[:fullURL]
Viewcounter.create(site_url: url)
end
```

also, I wrote this to take care of cross domain in config/application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
})
end
```

Then I created a HTML file where the above jQuery is written and opened it in a browser.

I expected jQuery to trigger action in controller and create a record in database.

But it did not. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: its not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve. However, from the looks of your code, I think you meant "POST" request ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data in your url

```
http://localhost:3000/viewcounter_controller/count?param_1=param1&param_2=param2
```

And then ask for the params in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$(function(){
  var webURL = window.location.href;

  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:3000/viewcounter/count?fullURL=' + webURL, 
   type: "GET"
  })
});
```